# Attribute not found:NoSuchAttributeException in tiles with Spring

Tags: spring, exception, tiles

I searched for all the questions asked on this site and tried all the changes but no luck. So posting the query here:

I am getting following exception:

```
HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.tiles.template.NoSuchAttributeException: Attribute 'body' not found.

type Exception report

message org.apache.tiles.template.NoSuchAttributeException: Attribute 'body' not found.

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.tiles.template.NoSuchAttributeException: Attribute 'body' not found.
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

org.apache.tiles.template.NoSuchAttributeException: Attribute 'body' not found.
    org.apache.tiles.template.DefaultAttributeResolver.computeAttribute(DefaultAttributeResolver.java:49)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.resolveAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:187)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.start(InsertAttributeModel.java:107)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:306)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.home_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f0(home_jsp.java:146)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:79)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.35 logs.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.35
```

I have my tiles.xml as:

```
<tiles-definitions>
  <definition name="base.definition" template="/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp">
         <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/menu.jsp" />
  </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

And finally my servlet-context.xml has following entries:

```
<beans:bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- 
    <beans:bean id="viewResolver" 
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewClass">
        <beans:value>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
        </beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
 -->
    <beans:bean id="tilesConfigurer" 
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

There is some commented part because I tried this answer from previously posted question but same problem occurred.

My POM.xml has following entries.(Just to be sure)

```
           <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I have this code in my home.jsp as:

```
<tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
```

And my menu.jsp is:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="search.htm">Search</a></li>
<li><a href="showMessages.htm">Messages</a></li>
<li><a href="contacts.htm">My Contacts</a></li>
<li><a href="change.htm">Password</a></li>
<li><a href="logout.htm">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

Please help. If anything else is needed, please ask.
thanks in advance.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: actually yes. You have to create a base definition first and then you have to extend that definition for all usage.
I will edit the post now.

Comment: @ArunM : I think it will work for you as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer after few changes in the tiles.xml

The main problem with it is that you can not use the definition directly. You have to extend it and then you can use it.

Refer this my edited code:

```
<definition name="new.definition" template="/WEB-INF/layout/newlayout.jsp"> 
<put-attribute name="title" value="" /> 
<put-attribute name="body" value="" /> 
<put-attribute name="menu" value="" /> 
</definition> 

<definition name="choice" extends="new.definition"> 
<put-attribute name="title" value="" /> 
<put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/choice.jsp" /> 
<put-attribute name="menu" value="" /> 
<put-attribute name="right" value="" /> 
    </definition> 

<definition name="logout" extends="new.definition"> 
<put-attribute name="title" value="Logging out.." />
 <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/logout.jsp" />
 <put-attribute name="menu" value="" /> 
<put-attribute name="right" value="" /> 
</definition>
```

As you can see, I initially created new definition as "new.definition" and then for choice and logout I am extending the existing definition.

Comment: Did not work for me unfortunately. I detailed the problem here .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947933/org-apache-tiles-template-nosuchattributeexception-attribute-dog-tiles-not-fo