# Getting NoSuchAttributeException while creating tiles with struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, attributes, tiles

I'm getting org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.NoSuchAttributeException: Attribute 'banner' not found. exception while running tiles project. Below is the code. I have downloaded one project from internet and ran it. It is working fine and I don't find any differences in both project. Still, below code is throwing an exception. Please advise.

**tiles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
           "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
           "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">


<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="baseLayout" template="/home.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Receipe Maker"/>
        <put-attribute name="banner" value="/banner.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/menu.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/about.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/footer.jsp"/>
    </definition>

    <definition name="teaLayout" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Tea Maker" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/tea.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="coffeeLayout" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Coffee Maker" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/coffee.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="milkShakeLayout" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Milk Shake Maker" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/milk-shake.jsp" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>
        <action name="*Menu" method="{1}" class="com.practice.tiles.MenuAction">
            <result name="home" type="tiles">home</result>
            <result name="tea" type="tiles">tea</result>
            <result name="coffee" type="tiles">coffee</result>
            <result name="milkShake" type="tiles">milk-shake</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**MenuAction.java**

```
package com.practice.tiles;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class MenuAction extends ActionSupport {

    /** */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7471860198571879105L;

    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }

    public String tea() {
        return "tea";
    }

    public String coffee() {
        return "coffee";
    }

    public String milkShake() {
        return "milk-shake";
    }

}
```

[image: Maven Dependencies]

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: May be this will help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752519/attribute-not-foundnosuchattributeexception-in-tiles-with-spring

Comment: Thanks Vel, it worked. I will post the changes which I made to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I have to make following changes to fix the problem:

First, I have created baseLayout and don't use it directly. Now tiles.xml looks like below code:

```
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="baseLayout" template="/baseLayout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Receipe Maker"/>
    <put-attribute name="banner" value="/banner.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/menu.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/about.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/footer.jsp"/>
</definition>

<definition name="home" extends="baseLayout">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Home"/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/home.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="tea" extends="baseLayout">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Tea Maker" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/tea.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="coffee" extends="baseLayout">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Coffee Maker" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/coffee.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="milkShake" extends="baseLayout">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Milk Shake Maker" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/milk-shake.jsp" />
</definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

Second, make sure result value in struts.xml must match with the attribute value of definition element in tiles.xml:
For instance, in struts.xml, result tag is: `<result name="teaValue" type="tiles">tea</result>`

The teaValue is returned by the action method which has executed and tea is the name of tiles definition.

That's it, now it is working.

Comment: It didn't explain why `NoSuchAttributeException` is thrown.